# Homogeneous forms of degree $d$ in quotient ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

We have a nice description for the space of all homogeneous elements of degree $d$ in $R = k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]$, namely it is isomorphic to $$(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})^d/(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})^{d+1}.$$

Now suppose I twist this a bit and consider a homogeneous ideal $I$ in $R$ and ask:

> > **My question is:** What is the space of all forms of degree $d$ in $R/I$ isomorphic to?

The situation is now a little more complicated because we are now looking in the quotient and the presence of the relation $F = 0$ means that a description of this space like say  $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})^d/(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})^{d+1}$ is not going to be accurate.

> > **Special Case:** If there is no general answer to my question, I am especially interested in the case that my ideal $I$ is generated by an irreducible form of degree $n$ with $d > n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R_+:=(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})$. Note that $I_d\subseteq R_+^d$. Since $I$ is homogeneous, you have
$$R/I = \bigoplus_{d\ge 0} R_d/I_d = \bigoplus_{d\ge 0} (R_+^d/R_+^{d+1})/I_d = \bigoplus_{d\ge 0} R_+^d/(I_d+R_+^{d+1}). $$
So, you get $(R/I)_d = R_+^d/(I_d+R_+^{d+1})$.

Comment: Dear Jesko, I don't understand some things in your answer. For example, how is $I_d$ a submodule of $R_+^d/ R_+^{d+1}$? Regards,

Comment: In the way in which $R_+^d/R_+^{d+1}\cong R_d$, as you pointed out in your question already. To be precise, $I_d\cap R_+^{d+1}=0$ by reasons of degree, so under the map $R_+^d \to R_+^d/R_+^{d+1}$, the subspace $I_d$ is mapped bijectively to its image.